# How to get Subscripting support in MonoTouch using iOS 5

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have the need to get [Subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) support using MonoTouch in order to avoid this errors

> -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b293f0

How can I do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after tons of trial and error and lot's of Miguel de Icaza's Help (Thanks a lot btw :) ) I found a way to solve this

The lib I am binding uses [Subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) and I needed a way to get [Subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) working on iOS 4.3 or above since this feature is going to be supported not until iOS 6.

So the `Solution` is to Statically compile against `libarclite` which you can find on the following locations (tnx again Miguel)

> Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a

Just built a [fat library](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linking_native_libraries#Building_Universal_Native_Libraries_%28i386.2c_ARMv6.2c_and_ARMv7%29) using `lipo` and added it to my binding project and voila.

Alex

Comment: I would warn you that Apple might not approve your application if it uses a library and/or feature not even released yet.

Comment: Yeah, but this library has already been deployed to appstore in several apps without issues :)

Comment: I had to specify  `SmartLink = false` inside the `.linkwith.cs` file in order to get everythink work.